# Why are you "On a train" yet "In a car" when you are inside both vehicles?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

Why are you "On a train" yet "In a car" when you are inside both vehicles?

"On a bike" makes sense but "On a plane" seems wrong as you are actually inside the plane rather than on it.

Comment: Seems to vary, depending on when the words were written: [Google NGram searcher.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+train%2Cin+a+train&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20train%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20train%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Even that Ngram can't really shed too much light on the question – not when there are so many hits like, "I fell asleep in a train seat," "he died in a train crash," "she was running around in a train station," and, "I was lost in a train of thought."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, the [metaphoric senses of ***get on*** and ***get in***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299) follow dimensionality:

- the object of *on* is a **Surface**, i.e, an object with 2 dimensions, or the surface of a 3-D object
- the object of *in* is a **Container**, i.e, a bounded 2-D or 3-D object

In terms of conveyances,

- humans get **on** *a raft, a horse, a bicycle, a sled, a wagon, a skateboard, a surfboard*
- humans get **in** *a car, a boat, a ship, a railroad car, a trolley, a bus, an airplane*

This much is predictable.

The problem arises with scheduled public conveyances; 
in that case only,
a human who gets **in** the conveyance physically
also is **on** the roster of passengers metaphorically
(*on the roster* is a 2-D "page/paper" metaphor).

So one can be said to **get on** *the bus, the plane, the train, the trolley*; but not *the taxi*.

Comment: I think it's more common to get **on a boat,** and aircraft terminology is largely borrowed from nautical, but otherwise I agree, this sounds right.

Comment: You get _on_ a large vessel, but that's because everything is flat, and it's a scheduled conveyance (whether public or not), so you're on the list. You get _in_ a rowboat, a canoe, or a kayak, however.

Comment: I think we get *on* a bus for the same reason we get *on* a skateboard: because during the act of boarding at least, and sometimes even during the ride, we are *standing* (**on** a surface which holds us up). When we get *in* a car, we do so by immediately and inevitably *sitting* (**in** seat which contains our body)

Comment: Good point. The posture of the agent may well make a difference; _stand_ is a [bedrock human reference](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf), for instance.

Comment: @JohnLawler You've pointed me to that paper before, and I've read it, and I found it *fascinating*. I even used it to support an argument over on Linguistics.SE!

Comment: Still a +1, but please expand upon "on a roster." If one refers to a roster as a physical/virtual page/surface, then yes, but a roster as a set (list, collection, etc) uses "in."

Comment: No, a _roster_ is a list on paper. _Roster_ may refer to the set of names on the list, but a roster is a physical thing at base, and since it refers to writing, it's two-dimensional. The fact is that metaphors like _list_ and _roster_ can be abstracted and often are confused with their abstract (set-theoretic or logical) avatars -- but they're always physical or physiological because that's all that humans really share.

Answer (score 4):

I remember different opinions on that:

> - When you get in the car, you get directly into your seat, while on public transport you have to walk to it (plane, train, bus).
> - You can stand up and walk around in public transport, thus the "on".
> - Public transport is "elevated", you need to go up a bit to get on it (stairs, platform).
> - "car" deriving from "carriage", a vehicle mounted with a car. That also explains why we get on the train, but in the train car.