# In a car or on a car?

Tags: prepositions

I know that normally we say travel by car or in a car, but  would it be acceptable to say 'on a car'?

Comment: Only if you're riding on the roof.

Comment: See *[Why are you "On a train" yet "In a car" when you are inside both vehicles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132102)* and the older *[Origin/reason for the expression “on the bus” instead of “in the bus”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251)* among others.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean on top of a car's roof then "on a car" would be correct. Otherwise it would be "in a car"

Honestly I don't see why "on a train" is correct english. "on a boat" makes sense, because originally people would stand on top of a boat. Same for "on a bike", since you're definitely not in it.

Comment: Board the train, board the plane - I think they're just parallels to boarding a ship, so then we also talk about being on the train or on the plane.