# Get onto/ into the train

Tags: grammar

I know "*to get onto the train*", but is it correct to say "*to get into the train*"?
If so, when do we have to use it?

Comment: You *board* a train.  Or you can get onto it.  Note that there are no "rules", though -- "into" is perfectly "legal", just not idiomatic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Origin/reason for the expression "on the bus" instead of "in the bus"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus). But it's really an *English Language Learners* question, as covered there by [“In” and “on”: How can I decide which one to use for vehicles?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155/)

Comment: Yes, there no rules.  But it's usually ON a train, boat, plane or bike, but IN a car.

Answer (score 0):

See @FumbleFingers comment for the typical answer, which is likely the one you're looking for.

With that said, "*to get into the train*" can still be perfectly correct in some cases.

For example:

> "The replicators managed to breach the train hull, and are now trying
>   to get into the train"

However, that is an exception. You would generally "board" a train, or get "onto" a train.