# Is it correct to use "on" with the meaning of "inside"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was wondering if it is correct to use "on" meaning that something is *on* (inside) something else. For example:

> There is a book on the drawer

If it is wrong, it is correct to use "in" instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the preposition "on" indicates that something is *on top* of something else; this can be either physically or not.

**On** also indicates "*with contact*", unlike **above** that indicates "*without contact*", see for example:

> - The book is **on** the table. [*the book is actually touching the table*]
> - He placed the lamp **above** the table. [*the lamp is not touching the table*]

To indicate *inside*, simply use "in":

> The book is in the drawer.

Comment: what about *on* the train, *on* the bus, *on* the plane? all cases where "on" means "inside", no?

Comment: Well, I think [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33140/is-there-a-rule-in-preposition-using/33148#33148) and also [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus) are a good start to explain why we have those cases.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I do not believe that "on" and "in" can be used interchangably.

If someone said to me "There is a book *on* the drawer" I would be confused because drawers are usually *inside* something else (such as a desk or a dresser) and it's not normally possible to be *on top of* something like a drawer, unless the drawer is extended. Only if the drawer is extended would it make sense to say " *on* the drawer" and it would mean (to me) that the book was resting across the rims of the drawer, but not actually inside the drawer.

If someone said "There is a book *in* the drawer" I would immediately open the drawer to look for the book. There would be no confusion about what the sentence means.

Comment: Is it not possible to use *drawer* in order to describe the container by extension?

Comment: @Eldros: I don't think so. A dresser can contain many drawers, some are side-by-side, some are stacked vertically. To say "it is *on* the drawer" then creates ambiguity: *Which* drawer? If it is a large desk with many drawers beside each other, which drawer should I look above?

Comment: Alright, let's say that was some brainf*$t from me, due in part to the fact I have to juggle between languages. :p

Comment: @Eldros: Fair enough, I wish I could competently handle more than just one language! ;)

Comment: This subthread has made me realize how weird a word "drawer" is.  Now I can only think of it referring to someone who is drawing a picture.

Comment: @fluffy: or someone who draws water out of a well.

Answer (score 1):

In the case *on* would mean at the top of the drawer. And yes, *in* would have the same meaning as *inside*.

> There is a book *in* the drawer