# Why "step into a car" but "step onto a plane"

Tags: prepositions

Why do we say *stepped into a car* with cars but can't say the same with planes? Instead we say *stepped onto a plane*.

Comment: Related: [When should I use “in” or “on”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/246/127)

Comment: Why no comma before but?

Comment: That edit does not belong to me. It belongs to @Will Hunting. I just edited the tag.

Comment: Are cars the exception?  We get into a car but onto a plane, ship, train, bus, elevator... what else do we get *into*?

Comment: What about submarines? They're certainly claustrophobic enough to use *into,* and [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into+a+submarine%2C+onto+a+submarine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that people generally do.

Comment: To make things worse, once you get into a submarine, you are onboard, just like a boat or airplane.

Comment: The comment with the diagrams... I love the idea that people were discussing getting onto or into a plane a full century before the Wright brothers.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly because aviation language has a certain amount in common with maritime language, and we get *onto* a boat.

Comment: I get *into* dinghies and kayaks and the like. I do get *onto* personal watercraft, but that's more analogous to mounting a bicycle or a horse than boarding a vessel.

Comment: Indeed @choster, definitely use caution when choosing between `into` or `onto` to describe the horse.

Comment: @JohnK Now now, let's get back onto the subject and not into that.

Answer (score 6):

Scale often matters. One steps into a canoe or rowboat but onto a yacht or an ocean liner, into a car or van but onto a bus or train. Most of the aircraft most people board are large commercial airliners, not small private planes.

Answer (score 4):

Mentioned this elsewhere, but it seems the controlling idea is whether the user normally sits or stands.  If the user is "in" the boat, it is a small boat and the user is typically sitting. If "on" the boat, users are comfortable standing. The same applies to planes, buses,trains, automobiles, and elevators.  For things that are straddled - fences, horses, bicycles, farm tractors - "on" is used.

Answer (score 2):

I think your premise is faulty. I think either "into" or "onto" works just fine. Google Ngrams shows these results for the following phrases:

[stepped into the plane vs. stepped onto the plane](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stepped+into+the+plane%2C+stepped+onto+the+plane&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image: Ngram chart for the above phrase]

[into the plane vs. onto the plane](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into+the+plane%2Conto+the+plane&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image: Ngram chart for the above phrase]

[into the airplane vs. onto the airplane](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into+the+airplane%2Conto+the+airplane&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image: Ngramchart for the above phrase]

(No hits at all for "stepped into the airplane vs.  stepped onto the airplane".)

---

That being said, I personally would use "onto the plane". I feel this is due to the relative size of the vehicle. If I were entering a small plane (like a two-seater) or a helicopter, I would use "into". In general, I think it's because of the feeling of being enclosed in the vehicle. So small vehicles, like cars and kayaks, get "into". Large vehicles, like commercial aircraft and cruise ships, get "onto". (I just noticed that @choster wrote the same thing in his own answer.)

Comment: Not truly surprising there was a massive uplift in 'into a plane' right around the time thousands of pilots around the world were flying tiny aircraft into unknown dangers. Compare that to the gradual rise in commercial passengers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer on ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19762), I think these are the rules:

1. If the vehicle is *boardable* — you can be *on board it* — you're *on* it. Here, "on" is short for "on board".
   This covers planes, trains, buses, boats, spaceships, and so on.
2. If the vehicle is too small to actually have an inside to get into, you're *on* it.
   This covers bikes, skateboards, pogosticks, and so on.
3. In the remaining cases, you're *in* it.
   This covers cars, canoes, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because, conceptually, the purpose of a plane or boat is to hold you up, where you would otherwise fall. Whereas a car or submarine is foremost simply containing you.

Comment: And the purpose of a bus is?

Comment: Similar to a trolley, it's basically a platform that carries you around and you ride it in a sense like you ride a horse.

Comment: It's not just size. You step into a room or a stadium, but onto a stage.

Comment: The use of into or onto on some level has to do with elevation.

Comment: surely you can be both on and in a submarine?