# 'On a swing' vs 'in a swing'

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “in” or “on”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-in-or-on)

Would you say:

> A child is sitting in a swing.

or

> A child is sitting on a swing.

Is it the same case as:  *in a chair* vs *on a chair*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. ***On* a swing** [is slightly more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20swing,%20in%20a%20swing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) now. Examples:

> I saw her sitting in a swing on her front porch. (See [this](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14318364) link for further examples with **in**).
>
> They are on the porch of some country inn, seated on a swing, gazing into each other's eyes... (see [this](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14318364) link for further examples with **on**)

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.