# "Sit in a chair" vs. "sit on a chair"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

What is the correct usage? I know you sit 'on' a sofa/couch. What about chair?

Comment: Related: [When should I use in or on?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-in-or-on)

Comment: You don't site "in" a sofa, as it's deep?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It depends on the kind of chair. You sit **on** a dining chair or an office chair, but **in** an armchair.

Answer (score 66):

Piggy-backing on Barrie's answer, you could you say that it depends on how relaxed your posture becomes. You sit **in** furniture where you lounge, and sit **on** seats where you sit more upright.

So, I'd be more likely to sit ***on*** a bench or ottoman, and more likely to recline ***in*** a rocker:

[image: Footrest] [image: Bench]

[image: Rocking Chair] [image: Blue Divan]

It might also depend on the verb you use, too.  Consider that blue divan: depending on how much I wanted to relax, I might either sit ***on*** it, recline ***on*** it, lounge ***in*** it, or lie ***on*** it...

Comment: I don't have words to describe how this answer helps a non native speaker in understanding the differences between "in" and "on" in this case. +100

Comment: dig the fainting couch.

Comment: I suppose it's like saying if someone is _on_ a bed they're sitting down or lying on the bed but if they are _in_ the bed they are under a blanket.

Comment: One pet peeve: **lay** is transitive; **lie** is intransitive - you can *lay* a comforter on a couch; you can *lay* **yourself** on the couch; but you *lie* on it.  People get this confused because **lay** is also the simple past of **lie**; "I lie dying" (now), but "As I lay dying" (in the past).

Comment: @MT_Head: Nice catch. (Note that those last three words weren't  part of my original answer; they were edited in.) Now for my pet peeve :^) it might have been better to just fix it with an edit, as opposed to leaving a comment.

Comment: @J.R. - Sorry - I didn't look at the edit history; I need to develop that habit!  Also, I've generally been reluctant to edit other people's answers; I'll try to get over that.

Comment: Thanks for editing my edit, that type of behavior is appreciated on this network.

Answer (score 15):

If it's a flat chair you sit *on* it. If it's something that covers you from almost three sides you sit *in* it.

Comment: And yet, as the OP says, we sit ON a sofa. Odd, eh?

Comment: @Barrie: maybe that's because the three sides are "stretched" apart far enough that one person is not really "in" it?  Using that logic, I'd sit **on** a loveseat, but a couple might sit **in** the loveseat. (Of course, a question like this is bound to be somewhat idiosyncratic.)

Comment: @J.R. Yeh, could well be. There's more variation in figurative uses: 'in the hot seat', for example.

Comment: @Barrie: or "off his rocker..."

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd say that you sit *in* a driving seat, but *on* an armchair.  The reason being that you're surrounded by a cage/frame or other structure as part of the seat.  So you're *in* an aeroplane seat, or *in* a train seat (as the seats are fixed or designed specifically for that environment) but *on* a dining chair or *on* a sofa as they're more "generic" ?