# ON or AT the surface of the shell?

Tags: prepositions

On the wall, at the table but how to say ON or AT the surface of the shell?

Comment: On.  Incidentally, *at the table* does not mean the same thing as *on the table* so it's not really an option.

Comment: You can be "on the surface of the frozen lake" or "at the surface of the ocean". I'd say if you're standing, your feet planted firmly on the shell, you're *on* the surface; if you can approach the shell from below as well as above, you're *at* the surface.

Comment: What is the surface of a shell?

Comment: **The** shell? Which one? _Shell_ has a number of meanings.

Comment: See LINKED sidebar also [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17440)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78496)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246)

Answer (score 3):

Certainly both are correct, but *on the surface* implies floating on the water like a boat, and *at the surface*  implies something has risen to the surface like a submarine .